# why are csvs copied from QPAD and csvs saved from q process so different in terms of size?

Tags: kdb

I am trying to save a csv generated from a table.

If I 'Export all as CSV' from QPAD the file is 22MB.

If I do  `` `:path.csv 0: csv 0: table `` the file is 496MB.

The file contains same data.

I do have some columns which are list of dates, list of symbols which cause some issues when parsing to csv.

To get over that I use this `` {`$$[1=count x;string first x;`$" "sv string x]} ``

i.e. one of the cols is called allDates and looks like this:

| someOtherCol | allDates | stackedSymCol |
| --- | --- | --- |
| val1 | , 2001.01.01 | , `sym 1 |
| val2 | 2001.01.01 2001.01.02 | `sym 2`sym 3 |

Where is this massive difference in size coming from and how can I reduce the the size.

If I remove these 3 columns which are lists of lists, the file goes down significantly.

Doing an `ungroup` is not an option.

I think the important question here is why is QPAD capable to handle columns which are lists of lists of type 'D' 'S' etc and how I can achieve that without casting those columns to a space delimited string. This is what is causing my saved csv to be so massive.

ie. I can do an 'Export all to csv' from QPAD on this and it is 21MB :
[image]

but if I want to save it programatically, I need to change those allDates and DESK_NAME column and it goes up to 500MB

UPDATE: Thanks everyone. I did not know that QPAD is truncating data like that on exports. That is worrying.

Comment: My first instinct would be to say those files are NOT identical if there is such a huge difference in size. Can you use `read0` to read the contents and then compare both with `~` to see if they are different?

Comment: when I say identical, I mean they are sourced through the same function, same method, same extraction. one is saved from q process and the other is copy pasted from the QPAD output. They're definitely not ~ identical

Comment: If they aren't identical using `~` doesn't that go some way to answering the question? You need to review the contents of each to see how they differ, even as simple as doing a character count from each file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on the update to your answer it seems you are exporting the data shown in the screenshot which would not be the same as the data you are transforming to save to csv directly from q.
[image]

Based on the screenshot it is likely the csv files are not identical for at least 3 reasons:

1. QPad is truncating the nested dates at a certain length
2. QPad adds `enlist` to nested lists of length 1
3. QPad adds/keeps backticks before symbols

## Example data comparison

Here is a minimal example that should highlight this:

```
q)example:{n:1 2 20;([]someOtherCol:3?10;allDates:n?\:.z.d;stackedSymCol:n?\:`3)}[]
q)example
someOtherCol allDates
                        stackedSymCol
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1            ,2006.01.13
                        ,`hfg
1            2008.04.06 2008.01.11
                        `nha`plc
4            2009.06.12 2016.01.24 2021.02.02 2018.09.02 2011.06.19 2022.09.26 2008.10.29 2010.03.11 2022.07.30 2012.09.06 2021.11.27 2017.11.24 2007.09.10 2012.11.27 2020.03.10 2003.07.02 2007.11.29 2010.07.18 2001.10.23 2000.11.07 `ifd`jgp`eln`kkb`ahm`cal`eni`idj`mod`omb`dkc`ogf`eaj`mbf`kdd`hip`gkg`eef`edi`jak
```

I have used 'Export All to CSV' to save to `C:/q/qpad.csv`.

I couldn't get your "razing" function to work as-is so I modified it slightly and used that to convert nested lists to strings and saved the file to csv.

```
q)f:{`$$[1=count x;string first x;" "sv string x]}
q)`:C:/q/q.csv 0: csv 0: update f'[allDates], f'[stackedSymCol] from example
```

Reading from both files and comparing the contents results in mismatched contents.

```
q)a:read0`:C:/q/q.csv
q)b:read0`:C:/q/qpad.csv

q)a~b
0b
```

#### Side note

Since kdb+ V4.0 2020.03.17 it is possible to save nested vectors to csv using `.h.cd` to prepare the text. The variable `.h.d` is used as the delimiter for sublist items.

```
q).h.d:" ";
q).h.cd example
"someOtherCol,allDates,stackedSymCol"
"8,2013.09.10,pii"
"6,2007.08.09 2012.12.30,hbg blg"
"8,2011.04.04 2020.08.21 2006.02.12 2005.01.15 2016.05.31 2015.01.03 2021.12.09 2022.03.26 2013.10.15 2001.10.29 2011.02.17 2010.03.28 2005.11.14 2003.08.16 2002.04.20 2004.08.07 2014.09.19 2000.05.24 2018.06.19 2017.08.14,cim pgm gha chp dio gfc beh mbo cfe kec jbn bjh eni obf agb dce gnk jif pci ppc"

q)`:somefile.csv 0: .h.cd example
```

## CSV saved from q

Contents of the csv saved from q and the character count are shown in the example:

```
q)read0`:C:/q/q.csv
"someOtherCol,allDates,stackedSymCol"
"8,2013.09.10,pii"
"6,2007.08.09 2012.12.30,hbg blg"
"8,2011.04.04 2020.08.21 2006.02.12 2005.01.15 2016.05.31 2015.01.03 2021.12.09 2022.03.26 2013.10.15 2001.10.29 2011.02.17 2010.03.28 2005.11.14 2003.08.16 2002.04.20 2004.08.07 2014.09.19 2000.05.24 2018.06.19 2017.08.14,cim pgm gha chp dio gfc beh mbo cfe kec jbn bjh eni obf agb dce gnk jif pci ppc"

q)count raze read0`:C:/q/q.csv
383
```

## CSV saved from QPad

Similarly the contents of the csv saved from QPad and the character count:

```
q)read0`:C:/q/qpad.csv
"someOtherCol,allDates,stackedSymCol"
"1,enlist 2006.01.13,enlist `hfg"
"1,2008.04.06 2008.01.11,`nha`plc"
"4,2009.06.12 2016.01.24 2021.02.02 2018.09.02 2011.06.19 2022.09.26 2008.10.29 2010.03.11 2022.07.30 2012.09.06 2021.11.27 2017.11.24 2007.09.10 2012.11.27 ...,`ifd`jgp`eln`kkb`ahm`cal`eni`idj`mod`omb`dkc`ogf`eaj`mbf`kdd`hip`gkg`eef`edi`jak"

q)count raze read0`:C:/q/qpad.csv
338
```

## Conclusion

We can see from these examples the points outlined above. The dates are truncated at a certain length, `enlist` is added to nested lists of length 1, and backticks are kept before symbols.

The truncated dates could be the reason why the file you have exported from QPad is so much smaller. Based on your comments above the files are not identical, so this may be the reason.

TL;DR - Both files are created differently and that's why they differ.

Answer (score 5):

These csvs will not be identical. qPad truncates nested lists(including strings). The csv exported directly from kdb will be complete.

Eg.

```
([]a:3#enlist til 1000;b:3#enlist til 1000)
```

The qPad csv export of this looks like this at the end: `30j, 31j ...`.

Comment: so ... it's not possible to achieve the same optimised result exporting to csv from a q process ...

Comment: but it isn't optimised though? you are losing useful information?

Comment: I am fairly sure the csv I export from kdb and the one I export from QPAD have the exact same data. I don't select with my mouse and copy... I use the export to csv. 100% all data is there

Comment: I don't think they will. You should do as Thomas suggested and `read0` the qPad csv export to compare with kdb. Or alternatively look for a row which has lots of values nested in allDates or DESK_NAME to see if all values are in the qPad export.

Comment: If filesize is a concern, you could zip the csv for transport

Comment: Hey . you are right . the data is truncated. that is really f'ed up. it was right in the middle of the data set and I only checked ends and a few random indices here and there.