# kdb/Q Most efficient way to combine two symbol fields and be able to export table as csv?

Tags: concatenation, export, kdb

I have two fields in a table of type symbol that I've combined, and I want to be able to export this as a csv.

This is what I used to combine the fields:

```
mytable: update combined_field: (first_field, 'second_field) from my_table;
```

This creates a new field called combined_field, of type S and is a complex field.

When I try to save this table as a csv, I get the following error:

```
'type
[0]  save `mytable.csv
     ^
```

I know this is because of the combined_field field. In addition, Excel doesn't translate this combined field very well.

My question is whether there is a better way to combine two symbol fields together that will not cause these issues in Q. Can I change the types of the two fields to be strings, or is there a better way to do so?

Comment: Complex types for saving csvs is only supported in `V4.0 2020.03.17`. Thomas' answer to a similar question covers this and also an alternative solution similar to your suggestion with strings. " " separated strings are a good option for dealing with saving to csv in this case.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74540761/why-are-csvs-copied-from-qpad-and-csvs-saved-from-q-process-so-different-in-term/74545830#74545830

Answer (score 0):

If you need to keep symbol type in memory and can live with a delimiter, this is probably fastest:

```
mytable: update combined_field:` sv/: flip[(first_field;second_field)] from my_table;
```

If you can live with strings because this is just a temporary before going to CSV:

```
mytable: update combined_field:(string[first_field],'(" ",'string[second_field])) from my_table
```

And if you can't live with delimiters or strings, you can cast to a symbol again:

```
mytable: update combined_field:`$(string[first_field],'string[second_field]) from my_table
```